# To what extent did Crazy Rich Asians get subsidized by the Singaporian Government?

Tags: production, crazy-rich-asians

From what I can tell from interviews and such, *Crazy Rich Asians* was somewhat subsidized by the Singaporian Government. [No Film School](https://nofilmschool.com/2016/07/film-production-incentives-tax-incentives-movie-rebates#:%7E:text=Financial%20incentive%3A%20In%202004%2C%20the,production%20staff%2C%20and%20production%20services) says that films can be subsidized up to 50 percent, but I can’t find any exact numbers. Anybody know where I'd look or how I could tell?

Answer (score 2):

The film appears to have received a number of different government subsidies, largely in the form of "*support*" via the '[Film in Singapore Scheme](https://www.businessworld.in/article/Film-Incentives-Adopted-by-India-Other-Countries/17-02-2022-420852/)' (which provided a significant rebate on relevant in-country spending) rather than any significant amount of cash money that went toward the $30M budget for the making of the film itself.

A reasonable guess would be that this rebate equated to about 10-20% of the film's overall budget (or around $3-5M), but since the money came from a bunch of different support agencies in a wide variety of formats over multiple years, it's quite tricky to put a specific number on it.

Additional spending to promote the film has probably came to around $10-20M, but again it's impossible to distinguish this from other tourist-promotion-related spending.

Note that the actual cash grant portion is 'commercially sensitive' and neither Warner nor the Singapore Govt. are willing to disclose it.

> But although Singapore provided a production assistance grant to
> Warner Bros, all the creative choices were left to the filmmakers,
> said Ng.
>
> While Ng would not disclose the amount of grant money given to the
> studio, he said it was “a small fraction” of the film’s US$30 million
> (S$41 million) budget.
>
> <sub><sup>[Singapore banks on 'Crazy Rich Asians', its most ambitious Hollywood tie-up, to draw tourists](https://sg.style.yahoo.com/singapore-banks-crazy-rich-asians-ambitious-hollywood-tie-draw-tourists-100728083.html)</sup></sub>

---

Support came in the form of an ongoing multi-year support package from the Singapore Tourist Board in the form of marketing spend.

> Prior to the MoU, [STB](https://www.stb.gov.sg/content/stb/en/media-centre/media-releases/Singapore-Tourism-Board-partners-with-Warner-Bros.html) and WBD collaborated on international marketing for popular rom-com Crazy Rich Asians in 2018 and HBO’s Westworld Season 3 in Singapore in 2020.

Most of the money provided appears to have been in the form of rebates and expenses for internation travel rather than actual cash injection into the film's production budget.

> The Singapore Tourism Board introduced the "Film in Singapore
> Scheme," which promotes production in the country by subsidizing up to
> 50% of qualifying expenses incurred in Singapore, including local
> talent, production staff, and production services. Additionally, there
> are various grants available, including a "Production Assistance"
> grant that supports up to 40% of qualifying expenses.
>
> <sub><sup>[Film Incentives Adopted By India & Other Countries](https://www.businessworld.in/article/Film-Incentives-Adopted-by-India-Other-Countries/17-02-2022-420852/)</sup></sub>

and

> The SFC, for one thing, provided Crazy Rich Asians with a Production
> Assistance grant, which "provides funding for productions that
> highlight Singapore talents in credited roles, and infuse data and/or
> digital technologies into content for distribution on new and/or
> digital platforms".
>
> The SFC also facilitated the filming in Singapore locations such as
> Gardens By The Bay and Newton Circus by linking up the movie producers
> to local government agencies such as the Ministry Of Home Affairs and
> Land Transport Authority.
>
> Meanwhile, STB supported Singapore cast members in Los Angeles by
> pitching them for interviews and press opportunities in the United
> States. STB and SFC did not say, however, how much they spent
> supporting the movie.
>
> <sub><sup>[Crazy Rich Asians: A 'made with Singapore' blockbuster hit](https://www.straitstimes.com/lifestyle/entertainment/crazy-rich-asians-a-made-with-singapore-blockbuster-hit#:%7E:text=The%20SFC%2C%20for%20one%20thing,and%2For%20digital%20platforms%22.)</sup></sub>

Co-branded events have been provided to promote various films and TV shows that show Singapore on screen as a positive destination. This includes long-term multiyear partnerships with Warner Bros.

> [STB’s co-marketing efforts](https://www.stb.gov.sg/content/dam/stb/documents/corporate-publications/STB-AR-2018-19.pdf) of box-office hit Crazy Rich Asians
> included co-hosting the official after-party in Los Angeles in August
> 2018 with Warner Bros., and the roll-out of a three-day public pop-up
> event “Crazy Rich Singapore Week”, which brought together food,
> cocktails, art and music from Singaporean talents. STB also
> co-produced a series of videos with Warner Bros., showcasing
> Singaporean cast members sharing stories about the locations and
> cultures shown in the movie.

They also seem to have helped the film with the usual support for visas and filming permits, assistance with location scouting, etc etc.